# Automatically choose specific option from select field attribute based on inbound link / previous page?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I have three pages that each describe a product that we sell. Each of those pages has a button/link that says "buy now". Those links all take you to a single Ubercart product page with a select list attribute where they can select the name of any of the three products that I mentioned previously and add that product to their cart.

I'd like to have the name of the product from which they came automatically selected in that attribute field. Is there a way to do this via some kind of URL string, or another method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7), check your stuff (get parameter maybe), then apply the selected item though the [form api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)